# Unable to remove previous polyline from last search

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have a slight problem, I am unable to remove the previous polyline created from the previous search.

I have looked at google documentation​ but i am unable to find the right answers.

```
let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue   
for route in routes
        {

            let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
            print("routesOVER:",routeOverviewPolyline)
            let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue


            let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)


            let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
            if polyline != nil {
            print(polyline)
            polyline.strokeColor = .black
            polyline.strokeWidth = 10.0
            polyline.map = self.googleMaps
            }

        }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
```

in the google maps, 2 polylines are shown. 1 from the previous search and another from the current search

[Google Maps Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb3hd.png)

Comment: try to use self.googleMaps.clear() google function to remove the polyline. Before draw new search polyline.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the mapView before drawing to new polyline on the map.

```
self.googleMaps.clear()
```

But above code will clear pins on the map as well. your have to redraw your pins on the map as well

Comment: were would i place that code , do i put the code before creating the polyline or after @Taimoor

Comment: before creating polyline

Comment: ok, Merci Becoup  are you familiar with CMPedometer ? @Taimoor

Comment: your problem sovled or not ? yes i am familiar with CMPedometer